# ERROR: syntax error at or near "INTEGER"

Tags: java, postgresql, flyway

I am using Flyway to migrate PostgreSQL tables for a spring web app and thus, I've written a set of SQL queries which add columns to an existing table, e.g. :

```
ALTER TABLE table_1 ADD COLUMN table_value_x TYPE INTEGER;
ALTER TABLE table_1 ADD COLUMN table_value_y TYPE VARCHAR(100);
```

After deploying war file on Tomcat, I get the following error :

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "INTEGER"

Since Postgre is not so informative about its errors, I am looking for any kind of advice or suggestions on what this might be, thank you.

Comment: I believe you need to omit `TYPE`

Comment: Just read the examples of the documentation. TYPE is not there. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-altertable.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[According to the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-altertable.html), I believe you need to omit `TYPE`

```
ALTER TABLE table_1 ADD COLUMN table_value_x INTEGER;
ALTER TABLE table_1 ADD COLUMN table_value_y VARCHAR(100);
```

From the docs, the *TYPE* keyword is only used when you are changing the datatype of an *existing* column.

```
ALTER [ COLUMN ] column [ SET DATA ] TYPE data_type [ COLLATE collation ] [ USING expression ]
```

Answer (score 2):

The `TYPE` keyword is only used when changing (altering) the column datatype. For adding columns, omit the `TYPE` keyword, as Matt wrote, and as it is shown here in the examples of the documentation (at the end of the page): https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-altertable.html

Answer (score 2):

I suspect it might work if you get rid of the word 'TYPE'.

See example below, from the [Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-altertable.html) site.

```
ALTER TABLE distributors ADD COLUMN address varchar(30);
```

Edit:  I see a whole bunch of people beat me to it.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if you already fixed, but if someone still asking:

I fixed excluding classpath dependency in pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <classpathDependencyExcludes>
                    <classpathDependencyExclude>org.flywaydb:flyway-core</classpathDependencyExclude>
                </classpathDependencyExcludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```